# Force connect to Bluetooth device

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Bluetooth speaker in my house. Myself and my partner periodically connect to it using either our phones (2 × Android) or laptops (1 × MacBook and 1 × laptop PC) to play music whilst at home. As far as I know, it's only possible to have a single device connected to a Bluetooth device at any given time.

The problem arises when one of us wants to play music from a device, but we are unable to pair with the speaker because *some* other device in the house is already paired. There is no way (that I'm aware of) of knowing which device is already connected, or where in the house that device is. The Bluetooth device we're connecting to is a [StarTech Bluetooth wireless receiver](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00G2CQFT0/ref=pe_385721_37038051_TE_3p_dp_1) - a normal speaker actually connects to this receiver. Since this device has no menus of any sort, there's no way to just walk up to the receiver and press a 'disconnect' button. In fact, simply turning-off-and-on-again doesn't work, as the device automatically re-pairs with the last device it was connected to.

There doesn't appear to be an option on any of the devices to 'force pair' with the music receiver device. I totally understand that this would *normally* be a security concern, but this is a speaker device in our own home, so we'd like to find a way to be able to override this security and allow forcibly disconnecting of any existing paired connections.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Unfortunately you can't** force pair it. Unless you buy a new bluetooth speaker that allows multiple connections or comes with a software control panel such as the [BlasterAXX](https://us.creative.com/p/speakers/sound-blasteraxx-axx-200). It is understandable that once a connection is established another device should not be able to terminate this connection and force a new one.

Receivers that allow only one connection are doomed to reconnect to the last device connected and the only way to resolve it is to disconnect the other device. I had a number of receivers and bluetooth speakers in the past and I always ran around the house to find the device that is connected to the speaker. If the receiver is not configured by the factory to allow multiple connections then you can't do much. Unless you want to crack open the receiver and start messing around with the chips (which I am sure you wouldn't like to do)

The ones I used had a pairing button, that once I pressed it a new search began and I was able to connect a different device. You should check if there is a similar option.

The logical way to proceed in the future, is to turn off your bluetooth on the device, after you are done, so that the receiver is free for a new connection. Now, if you want to find which device is connected, you can always use your phone to scan for nearby devices and go check every one of them if it is connected to the receiver.

Another way is to configure your devices so that they wouldn't automatically connect to the receiver, but only when you desire to. I am sure that every single device, or computer you are using has the option to connect automatically or not.

I understand this is not what you would like to hear but there is no other way. That's a common problem with devices that don't have a control panel available. If you are not willing to spend some money on a new device then try any of the things I mentioned, and I would suggest to have the receiver free for connections when you are not using it.

Comment: See Brenner Henry's answer below - there's a slightly hacky but easy way to override a bluetooth connection.

Answer (score 5):

Actually there is a way to connect to a Bluetooth speaker that can only be connected to one device at a time when it is already connected to another device!

Make sure the Bluetooth speaker is off.

Go to settings, Bluetooth, and find your speaker (There should be a list of Bluetooth devices that you last connected to).

Tap on the Bluetooth speaker to connect, then turn the speaker on AFTER you pressed the connect button, while your device is trying to connect to it.

Your speaker then should connect to your device.

This trick worked for me and wanted to share this tip.

Comment: Brilliant! This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually possible by spoofing your bluetooth mac then jamming the bluetooth connection. If you are lucky you will be able to connect once you stop the jamming

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe that is the case in the question?

Answer (score 0):

If you connect to the device and then turn your speaker on, that usually works.

But for the times that it doesn't and reset by holding down the Bluetooth button and the power button for 3 to 5 seconds and than you are good to go.

Comment: As specified in the question, "there's no way to just walk up to the receiver and press a 'disconnect' button".

Answer (score 0):

I've found that putting the device into pairing mode will allow it to connect to another device. You don't actually need to re-pair it with the host, you can just initiate the connection normally from the host, and it should force a disconnect with the other device.

Comment: Unfortunately the device in the question doesn't have any way of "putting the device into pairing mode".

Answer (score 0):

If the device is portable simply walk away (with your device in hand) far enough that the device cannot find the the previous Bluetooth connection, then you will be able to connect your device without restriction. [I was using Xdobo X8 Bluetooth speaker]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks – useful if the device is portable (although in this case we are talking about a home stereo system)

Answer (score -1):

If you're in this situation and the other device is inaccessible (e.g. in a sleeping person's room) then see if there's a reset function on the speaker.

Sometimes there is a physical reset button - often it's a small hole which accepts a straightened paper clip. Other times one of the main buttons has dual actions, and if it's held longer it could cause the speaker to enter pairing mode. This may not be described in the manual.

Activating this reset should cause the speaker to forget it's previous connection and be available again.

(At least that's the case for my Aukey SK-30, pressing Mode for a few seconds resets the connection).

Comment: As specified in the question, "there's no way to just walk up to the receiver and press a 'disconnect' button".

Answer (score -1):

I'm confused by all the other answers saying it can't be done.  On just about every BT device that I've owned (and its been a few!), if the device is switched OFF and you hold down the power button for ~5 seconds, it goes into seeking/pairing mode.  From there you just go through pairing process again on your phone/laptop whatever.

It is a small amount of hassle, but easy.

Comment: "In fact, simply turning-off-and-on-again doesn't work, as the device automatically re-pairs with the last device it was connected to."

Comment: I'm not saying 'off and on', I'm saying 'off and long-press on'.

Comment: The device in question (https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00G2CQFT0/ref=pe_385721_37038051_TE_3p_dp_1) has no such feature.

Comment: Oh.  Sorry.

One option:  The StarTech device has NFC.  Do you have a mobile that you could use to (1) kick off the unwanted device?  (2) Then on the mobile go to Settings > Bluetooth and disconnect, thus freeing up the StarTech for the thing you actually want to be connected?

One final option is to ask their Live Chat (blue button on left hand side):  https://www.startech.com/AV/Converters/Audio/Bluetooth-Audio-Receiver~BT2A