# Can one bluetooth device (mouse) automatically connect to alternating devices (2 windows laptops) depending on whether they are up?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, mouse, bluetooth

I want to use my bluetooth mouse (Rapoo) with any of two laptops (running windows 8 and 10, resp.), depending on which laptop is powered up (I have only one up at any time).

What I would like to have is this (any sequence of the first 3 steps is good :-)

- turn on the laptop
- turn on the mouse
- press bluetooth pairing button on mouse
- running laptop connects

Right now, the only procedure which works halfway predictably is to

- turn on both devices
- go to laptop's bluetooth menu
- disconnect mouse (yes, it's shown as connected, although it was connected to the other laptop before, and it doesn't work with this one currently)
- press the bluetooth pairing button on mouse
- wait until laptop rediscovers the mouse
- pair laptop with mouse

Even this procedure is not reliable, as sometimes the device will not show up, or will not connect although it has been found.

All this is no issue when I power up the same laptop that the mouse was connected to before - there's an immediate connection to the mouse.

Is that an issue with Windows 8 or Rapoo mouses? Or just a bluetooth behavior?

My request sounds a little different than the one here [Force connect to Bluetooth device](https://superuser.com/questions/1211057/force-connect-to-bluetooth-device) - so maybe there's still one more trick.

Comment: Google "barrier software" https://github.com/debauchee/barrier

Comment: @Gantendo Thanks for the tip, but this sounds like both machines need to be running at the same time - as it talks about one being the server and that it allows to control one machine from the other... not quite what I was looking for ("only one up at any time").

Comment: I suggest just getting a mouse with multiple pairing slots.